# How to get the url of a file that is downloaded when clicking on a <div> tag

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, url

I am trying to figure out how to extract the URLs for the CSV files that are downloadable at a website.

The website has been created by an old version of the react. I used the "page source" to see what csv URLs existed, but the URLs mentioned in the page source download some old files from August and not the current file.

What is the proper way of figuring out how the file URLs are built?

I know posting a link is not recommended, but here is the link for the website that I am working on: https://ark-funds.com/download-fund-materials/

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

1-press F12 for Inspection mode

2-click on Network tab

3-download the file by clicking the Div

4-under Network, there will be the data which will show the url